# IronPython ArgumentTypeException custom class

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I'm just starting with IronPython and I have some difficulties to use my .NET dll

I've got two assemblies `assemblyA` and `assemblyB`, with `assemblyA` referencing `assemblyB`. In each assembly, I have a class with this kind of prototyping :

assemblyA

```
using assemblyB
namespace assemblyA
{
   public classA
   {
      private assemblyB.classB property;
      public assemblyB.classB Property {get;set;}
   }
}
```

assemblyB

```
namespace assemblyB
{
   public classB
   {
      private double variable;
      public double Variable{get;set;}
   }
}
```

In my code, I first load the two assemblies :

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\.....\assemblyA.dll')
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\.....\assemblyB.dll')
import assemblyA
import assemblyB

clA = assemblyA.classA() #ok
clB = assemblyB.classB() #ok
clA.Prop = clB #Error: expected classB, got classB
clA.Prop = assemblyB.classB() #of course same error
```

Any suggestion on how to fix the issue ? I guess it is because `assemblyB` is loaded two times but I only have one assemblyB.dll so why is it not recognized to be the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many and many trials, I finally found a solution. I simply add the path where to search for the dll in the system path, and let IronPython decide which one to load :

```
import sys, os, clr
sys.path.append(r'[MyPath for assemblyA]')
sys.path.append(r'[MyPath for assemblyB]')
clr.AddReferenceToFile('assemblyA.dll')
clr.AddReferenceToFile('assemblyB.dll')
```

This issue is related to https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/25124 and here I propose a workaround.